When a system is to evolve to a higher entropy state, will surroundings provide energy willingly for any required latent / barrier energy?
I have been studying Gibbs’ free energy equation and I have some questions regarding this. Let me first explain what I understand.
In any kind of change, entropy comes first. Which means if in a ‘to be’ evolved final state, the permutation of the microstate of the final state will be higher, then it is permissible to evolve to that state. But if not, it is very much less likely. Now when ice melts, its disorder increases that’s why we call it natural direction of time. But at the same time we would need some energy to make the transition due to conservation of energy; which is another law of nature. So next we ask where is this energy coming from? Answer is from surrounding. Why? Because our system (the ice) and the surroundings combined create a single system, which together would want to increase their entropy. And as energy of surrounding is much higher, so a little change doesn’t change its entropy much, so change of entropy of the ice is decisive here. And as in liquid form its disorder increases, nature should willingly provide the required energy for the change.
Now how much energy is this? How does nature calculate the required energy? Since entropy depends on internal energy, volume and number of particles, all of which give rise to different possible configurations, so any change in these quantities which show higher disorder, should be provided.
Now my question is, if there are some hindrance or barriers along the way, which doesn’t directly increase entropy but must be overcome, will nature acknowledge that and modify its energy budget accordingly? I mean, the latent heat to break the ice bonds, does it inherently increase entropy? Even after the bonds are broken, if additional translational energy isn’t provided to the system, the constituents will stay in respective locations and entropy will not increase. Furthermore, energy required to break the bonds is fixed, and only one way that can be provided. So there is no scope for any distribution or permutation here. Why would nature account for this latent energy?
What my understanding is, nature would look at the disorder difference between initial and final states and calculate the energy to be supplied, and if the barriers lying along the way are not as high as the to be exchanged energy, then the system may still evolve, but at a cost of not fully reaching the sought after final state, as some energy would be used up to overcome the barrier. But if the barrier energy is higher than TdS, then the system won’t just evolve as this is a contradictory situation.
Now in the expression dG=dH-TdS, shouldn’t we just compare TdS with the possible barrier energy? Why are we comparing it with the total change in enthalpy? Yes dH contains the needed energy to break the bonds, so we have to compare TdS with that energy, but it also contains PdV; or is the argument here is that the supplied TdS shouldn’t in totality be compared with barrier energy as some of it is needed so it can expand the system’s volume?
I may have gone in the wrong direction at the beginning. Please someone help me with these concepts.
